# Abort Ajax Request in other function

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

i want abort a Ajax request which is in an other function
Example:

```
var xhr = false;
$(function(e) {
     $(document).on('click', '.menue-button', function(e) {
         // Some JS
         xhr = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: index.php,
             //The ajax functions
          });
      });
});

$(document).on('click', '#progress-abort', function() {         
    xhr.abort();
});
```

The debugger says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

i know why, but i dont know how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It tried the following:

```
var xhr = false;
$(function(e) {
 $(document).on('click', '.menue-button', function(e) {
     // Some JS
     xhr = $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: index.php,
         //The ajax functions
      });
  $(document).on('click', '#progress-abort1', function() {
    xhr.abort();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#progress-abort', function() {         
      $('#progress-abort1').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

But the `'#progress-abort1` doesnt trigger. Whats wrong?